# Using replace on a string from select in MySQL with column data leads to same output for different rows

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do, which shows the problem best. My database looks like this:

users table:

| user_id | first_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Dave |
| 3 | Steven |

settings table:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| format_string | Hello {first_name}! |

Now I want to retrieve the format_string with inserted user data for every user.
If I hardcode the my format_string into my SQL like this, it works:

```sql
SELECT first_name,
REPLACE(
    "Hello {first_name}!",
    "{first_name}",
    first_name
)
AS greeting
FROM users
```

I get this output, which is expected:

| first_name | greeting |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Hello Bob! |
| Dave | Hello Dave! |
| Steven | Hello Steven! |

But if I use the format_string from my settings table, like this:

```sql
SELECT first_name,
REPLACE(
    (SELECT value FROM settings WHERE name = "format_string"),
    "{first_name}",
    first_name
)
AS greeting
FROM users
```

I get this output, which is absolutely not expected:

| first_name | greeting |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Hello Bob! |
| Dave | Hello Bob! |
| Steven | Hello Bob! |

Does anyone know what the problem there is and how to fix it?

Comment: I have filed [MariaDB bug reports](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-community-bug-reporting/) in the past and found the team to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain what the problem is. You might have found a bug in the database engine. I don't have access to newer MariaDB (dbfiddle's newer versions seem broken), but while both MariaDB 10.3 and MySQL 5.5 seem to give your output, MySQL 5.6 gives the expected one, so the bug was found and fixed.

Rewriting your query with a join instead of a subquery seems to work in any engine:

```
SELECT REPLACE(settings.value, "{first_name}", users.first_name) as greeting
FROM
  users,
  settings
WHERE settings.name = 'format_string';
```

- [dbfiddle for MariaDB 10.3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=cb5a71e2d50cbc7ffb12ca3e9efee959) (weird)
- [dbfiddle for MySQL 5.5](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=cb5a71e2d50cbc7ffb12ca3e9efee959) (weird)
- [dbfiddle for MySQL 5.6](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=cb5a71e2d50cbc7ffb12ca3e9efee959) (okay)

Comment: Thank you! I'm using MariaDB 10.4. Might really just be a bug, couldn't find any report on it though. Your workaround with join works though, thank you very much! I'll just wait a bit to accept your answer though, in case anyone knows more about the problem/bug ;)

Comment: Oh, and also I guess this solution will cause problem, if I have two different format_strings in my setting table, and want to use each in a different column... but luckily I don't need that (yet)

Comment: No matter how you go about it, you need a way to differentiate the different format strings in order to be able to reference them. If you have a specific example, I can try to address it (e.g. you can join the table again with a different alias for another format string)

Comment: Oh, I tried the one with alias, that worked! Essentially I head: `SELECT users.first_name, REPLACE(format_string_1.value, "{first_name}", users.first_name) as greeting, REPLACE(format_string_2.value, "{first_name}", users.first_name) as greeting_2 FROM users, settings as format_string_1, settings as format_string_2 WHERE format_string_1.name = "format_string" AND format_string_2.name = "format_string_2";` - just leaving that there in case people search for this in the future ;)